# Induction Hypothesis Should there be a plus sign

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

> $$\sum_{i=0}^n2^i=2^{n+1}-1.$$

After going through the steps I come up with
$$2^{k+1}+1,$$
And I expected
$$2^{k+1}-1.$$

Therefore it is false.

Can someone check and see if this is correct?
I can't find a way to validate my answer.

Comment: Why not check an example of two?  That will immediately tell you which formula is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second step of the induction requires that:

if we suppose $\sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i=2^{n+1}-1$ then it is true also for $n+1$? I mean it is true that $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}2^i=2^{n+2}-1$? Yes, in fact by induction hypothesis:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}2^i=\sum_{i=0}^{n}2^i+2^{n+1}=2^{n+1}-1+2^{n+1}=2(2^{n+1})-1=2^{n+2}-1$.

Comment: I was going in circles with this concept. There was a mixed bag way about how it was being taught on the net. Susanna S. Epp's book and your input here saved my day - actually days and night. Thank you very much!

Comment: @coder3 You're welcome!